# How can I enlarge the fonts on Wikipedia in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, fonts, zooming

On most web sites, when I look at them with Chrome on my phone (a Nexus 4 running stock Android 4.2.2), I can adjust the font size by double-tapping a column of text to make it widen to fill the screen.  However, this doesn't work on Wikipedia.org; I don't know why -- the text is quite small.

I've already got the browser set up to display (very) large fonts: I'd gone to "settings", "Accessibility", and have cranked the "Text scaling" slider over to 155%, which is ginormous.  (There's also a check in the box that says "Force Enable Zoom", which I don't recall setting; I guess that's the default).

Anyway: this feature works fine on most sites, just not Wikipedia (and perhaps a few others).  Any advice for making Wikipedia readable?

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem on my Galaxy Nexus. Are you using the mobile version of the site (`en.m.wikipedia.org`)? Have you considered using the [Wikipedia app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wikipedia)? (There, at least, you can increase the font size to 300%.)

Comment: Hi Al, thanks for checking!  Yes, it's the mobile version of the site (oddly, asking for the desktop version doesn't change that).  I have indeed tried the Wikipedia app; I can't at the moment remember why I no longer use it; I'll give it another look.

Comment: Turns out the Wikipedia app works well enough.I still don't know why Chrome works the way it does, but the standalone app is good enough.

Comment: I'm having same problem with Nexus 7/Android 4.3/Chrome 30.0.1599.92. Seems like text scaling works as it should with, say, text-boxes like their one I'm typing this message in, but not on regular paragraphs: it just fits the paragraph on the screen.

Comment: Websites can ask the browser not to allow the user to scale it, that's why you can't zoom in.

Comment: @AlexDumitru I'd heard that, but I assume that the "Force Enable Zoom" checkbox is meant to override that.

Comment: I have force enable zoom, but it does not help on some forums. I can zoom but the text is not reflowed, forcing me to scroll back and forth. e. g. http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-831956-start-0.html

Comment: I've given up on the Wikipedia app (I can't remember why); and I've noticed that (contrary to one of my previous comments), asking for the "Desktop version" of the app _does_ help (this is on Android 4.4.2, now; perhaps the browser behaves differently).  I still know of no way to _always_ make Wikipedia pages expand when I double-tap; but at least I can request the desktop version for any individual page, and then double-tap.

Comment: Wow seeing this thread from 9 years ago and realizing that since I still have the EXACT problem as OP doesn't give me much hope! The font size on Wikipedia does NOT respond to ANY of the settings on my phone. I cranked the fonts up so big I hardly get 2 words per line everywhere else, but once I go back to a wiki page, it is so small I literally had to get reading glasses to use it. If I pinch-zoom the text does not reflow to fit the page forcing me to scroll back and forth to read an article and that ain't happening, lol!

Comment: I've been using the Wikipedia app for ages, and despite my comment from 2013(!) it seems fine.